# How to create a simple workflow in Sharepoint 2010 for moving data from one list to another based on a set of conditions

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to apparently make data from one list to be moved to another list in the same site based on  a set of conditions .

Ex :

> Say If  list1 has data fields SID, ORG , ACTION , PATTERN with each
>   data field  having a set of options from which the entry should be
>   made. List 2 has data fields  LSID,LORG ,LACTION, LPATTERN.

When an data entry is made in the List 1 and submitted the workflow should compare the value in the Data filed ACTION  against the static defined set of values and accordingly move the data entry made in List1 to the specified lists that we have in the same site.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Workflow on List1 and set it to run on 'Item Created'. In the Workflow add a condition, say If 'Status = Approved' then in Action, write 'Copy List Item', select 'Current Item' and the desired list name say 'List2' which must have same number of columns with same data type.
Thats it.
If you are planning to move item from one list to another, then post copy action you can delete the current item from List1 by the action named 'Delete Item'.

Below is the attached image.

[image]